# GWT Eclipse change web page background color?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

How to change the background color of a web page in GWT? I am coding in MVP and using absolute panel as the base panel e.g.

```
AbsolutePanel absolutePanel;
etc..
absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();
absolutePanel.setSize(Window.getClientWidth() + "px", Window.getClientHeight() +        "px");
absolutePanel.addStyleName("boardBackground");
initWidget(absolutePanel);
```

The problem is when I ran the program, there is a white border around the panel, is there other way to color the whole page? Thanks.

Comment: Elaborate on the "base panel": do you mean the Root Panel?

Comment: No, I'm not using HTML, the absolute panel is where I put my widgets.

Answer (score 0):

## Elaborate the Question Please

If you want to change web page background colour, Do it in your application HTML file. If you want to do it for your panel, use a stylename and do whatever you want.... if styles are overridden in your css class, use ***!important***